# jQuery setTimeout for drop down navigation

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, settimeout

I'm using a jQuery-based drop down menu and would like to add a delay to the drop down animation (slideDown). I looked around to see how to implement setTimeout but couldn't get it to work with my code. Can anybody help?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function megaHoverOver(){
        $(this).find(".sub").slideDown(500);    
    }

    function megaHoverOut(){ 
        $(this).find(".sub").slideUp(150);      
    }

    var config = {    
         sensitivity: 2, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
         interval: 0, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
         over: megaHoverOver, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
         timeout: 0, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
         out: megaHoverOut // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
    };

    $("#mainnav-first li").hoverIntent(config);
});
```

By the way, I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function megaHoverOver(){
        $(this).find(".sub").slideDown(500);    
    }, 500);

    function megaHoverOut(){ 
        $(this).find(".sub").slideUp(150);      
    }

    var config = {    
         sensitivity: 2, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
         interval: 0, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
         over: megaHoverOver, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
         timeout: 0, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
         out: megaHoverOut // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
    };

    $("#mainnav-first li").hoverIntent(config);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve that using delay():

```
$(this).find(".sub").delay(500).slideDown(500);
```

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: I did try .delay, but I don't want the drop down to come down if the user rolls out of the trigger. .delay will cause the animation to happen no matter what.